# error accountType is a variable but it is used as a type?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fix my code but can't seem to get around it. I have a main abtstract class Account and 4 sub classes: CurrentAccount, SavingsAccount, StudentAccount and YoungSavingsAccount
I have a class Customer which is trying to create an account and it can only have 1 of each type of account. The Customer class has a private field called AccountsOwned which is an array of Accounts. But my problem is that I cannot use the paramater accountType which is of type Type. here's my code for the function in the Customer Class:

```
 public bool CreateAccount(Type accountType, int accountNumber, int sortCode, decimal balance)
        {
            // if user already has the same account type, cannot create account and return false
            if (_accountsOwned.OfType<accountType>().Any()) // error here
                return false;
            // else create an account depending on the account type
            else
            {
                if (accountType == CurrentAccount)
                {
                    var account = new CurrentAccount(accountNumber, sortCode, balance);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (accountType == SavingsAccount)
                {
                    var account = new SavingsAccount(accountNumber, sortCode, balance);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (accountType == StudentAccount)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Course Code");
                    var courseCode = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Institution Name");
                    var institution = Console.ReadLine();
                    var account = new StudentAccount(accountNumber, sortCode, balance, courseCode, institution);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (accountType == YoungSavingsAccount)
                {
                    var account = new YoungSavingsAccount(accountNumber, sortCode, balance);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

I get an underline under accountType in the first if statement. and it says "accountType is a variable but it is used like a type". any thoughts?

Comment: You want `if (accountType == typeof(CurrentAccount))`. [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) returns the `Type` of the type, which is what you are equality comparing here (is this Type the same as that Type).

Comment: I think you want something like TypeOf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx and not just a comparison.

Comment: accountType is indeed a variable.

Comment: Oh I just saw your comment hidden in the code, "error here". Depending on what's in your list you should be able to do `if (_accountsOwned.Contains(accountType)) {return false;}`, assuming you do something like `_accountsOwned.Add(typeof(Thing))` or `_accountsOwned.Add(a Type object)`.

Comment: when I do the if (_accountsOwned.Contains(accountType)) I get an error under the _accountsOwned stating: Account[] does not contain a definition for 'contains' and the best extension method overload 'Querable.Contains<Type>(IQueryable<Type>,Type) requires a receiver of type IQueryable<Type>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accountType` is a variable that contains a Type value.
This value will vary at runtime, it might be different each time your method is called, but the method does not change.

The `OfType<>` extension method wants a type parameter known at compile time.
If you use `OfType<>` with different parameters, your program will actaully call different methods under the hood, based on that parameter.

Instead of `OfType<>`, you can say `_accountsOwned.Any(x => x.GetType() == accountType)`. This comparison will be done at runtime.